# Why does this inputs value keep giving me undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to send of the result from a `onClick` event with the value of the input, but the value keeps saying `undefined`. But if I `console.log` the whole `ref`, I can see that the `ref` is connected to an input.

This is what I've tried so far:

**The input:**

```
<Input
  placeholder="Projektnamn"
  ref="projectName"
  action={
    <Button
      style={{ backgroundColor: "#68478D" }}
      icon="tasks"
      content="Skapa dokument"
      onClick={() => this.createClicked()}
    />
  }
  style={{ padding: "50px" }}
/>
```

**The method:**

```
createClicked = () => {
  console.log(this.refs.projectName)
  let owner = "test";
  let projectName = this.refs.projectName.value;
  this.props.fetchNewProject('/api/create-project', {owner, projectName});
}
```

Comment: Have you written the `Input` and `Button` components yourself? Can you include them in your question?

Comment: No I haven't It's from semantic ui : https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the `this.refs.projectName.inputRef.value` in your callback.

**Example**

```
class App extends Component {
  createClicked = () => {
    console.log(this.refs.projectName.inputRef.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Input
        placeholder="Projektnamn"
        ref="projectName"
        action={
          <Button
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#68478D" }}
            icon="tasks"
            content="Skapa dokument"
            onClick={this.createClicked}
          />
        }
        style={{ padding: "50px" }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if that's material-ui elements or similar then they follow the convention of adding the type after the ref:

```
this.refs.projectName.input.value
```

Comment: When I did that, i got this "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" :/
Thank you for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

Send your event through:

```
onClick={(e) => this.createClicked()
```

Then read it:

```
createClicked = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
}
```